# How to design a search box for a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, searchbar

I got a customize li filter for a website but I need to hide the all li in the initial stage. I need to hide all li in the page and show only the searching li. But the problem is when I try to hide the li, it also block all the li during result.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search...">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">tree</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">bike</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">sea</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">mobile</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide all the `li` elements if the input is an empty string i.e. `""` and run the function when the user types in input and the first time when the JS loads.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  if (input.value === "") {
    [...li].forEach((liElement) => {
      liElement.style.display = "none";
    });
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search...">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">tree</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">bike</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">sea</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">mobile</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do the same search filter by using the class attribute instead of using it's name.

Comment: yeah, why not. But to be clear about class. `class` should be used to give to multiple elements, if you want to filter them then yes, you can do this. First, select all element and then filter elements that have that class using `element.classList` property

Comment: can you please explain me with the working code

Comment: Dude sure I can, Isn't that be better if you could ask this question here in SOF, instead of asking in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I've quickly refactored you code so it support multiple values and preserves the list with links in case you wanted that.

This also only creates the list items that match the search term.

I don't know if this is better for performance but it's easier to add elements to the array rather than create html elements to hold the values.

```js
    function myFunction() {
        let ul = document.querySelector('#myUL')
        ul.innerHTML = '';
        
        let inputVal = document.querySelector("#myInput").value;
        if(inputVal.length == 0){
            return;
        }

        
        let possibleValues = ['tree', 'bike', 'sea', 'mobile'];
        
        let resSpan = document.querySelector('#res');
        let resVal = [];
        
        
        possibleValues.forEach(str => {
            if(str.includes(inputVal)){
                resVal.push(str)
            }
        })
        
        if(resVal.length > 0){
            resVal.forEach(v => {
                let newLi = document.createElement('li');
                let newAnc = document.createElement('a');
                
                newAnc.innerText = v;
                newLi.appendChild(newAnc);
                ul.appendChild(newLi);
            })
        } 

        
    }
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search...">
    <ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants. If you search for `e` and then remove the search value then it doesn't clear the result.

Comment: `e` only search for single `mobile` what about other results...

Comment: @decpk I've fix it

Answer (score 0):

Alright, below is a working version of your code. I know this question has already been answered, but this version supports multiple `li`s coming up as search results:

(Made 2 changes - the `li`s start of hidden, and then re-hide when the search bar is empty)

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 && filter.length > 0) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search...">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li style="display:none;"><a href="#">tree</a></li>
  <li style="display:none;"><a href="#">bike</a></li>
  <li style="display:none;"><a href="#">sea</a></li>
  <li style="display:none;"><a  href="#">mobile</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
const ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
const li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (i of li) i.style.display = "none" ;

function myFunction() {
  let filter, a, i, txtValue;
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  if (filter) {
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "block";
      } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }else for (i of li) i.style.display = "none" ;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search...">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">tree</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">bike</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">sea</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">mobile</a></li>
</ul>
```